# How would I import a library to a java selenium project?

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to use the java library Faker, which generates fake data.

```
http://dius.github.io/java-faker/
```

Since I can't import it, how can I add the files from the zip into my project.

This is my current project structure

```
Project
   src
     default package
       FirstProgram.java
   JRE System Library
   Referenced Libraries
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `Zip`.
Right Click on `Referenced Library` -> `Build Path`-> `Configure Build Path` 
Import the extracted zip in your library